# Doxygen drawing vertical inheritance diagram

Tags: html, c++, inheritance, doxygen

I have my code documented with Doxygen comments.
I have it printing inheritance and collaboration diagrams.

The inheritance diagram is printed horizontally (landscape), while the collaboration diagram is printed vertically (portait).

The for C++ classes, with long inheritance tree, inheritance diagram would be easier to print if it were vertical (portrait).

I searched the web for "Doxygen inheritance vertical" and there were no results about how to change the orientation of the inheritance diagram.

The manual (online version) only defined the inheritance graph option, but no method to set its orientation.

How do I tell Doxygen to draw the inheritance diagram in portrait (vertical) orientation?
(I am using the DOT options and the output format is HTML).

Comment: I was looking for the same option, and could not find it.
Maybe we could write a feature request?

Comment: I just sent a feature request to their mailing list...